# rsyslog send logs of tag to specific file with different template

Tags: rsyslog

I have a script that uses the logger command to log things to rsyslog.
I want all logs from this script to go to /var/log/xen-shutdown-script.log

The logs don't seem to be sent to this log file.

Example logger command:
`logger -t xen-shutdown-script -p syslog.info "test message"`

I have the following in a file in path '/etc/rsyslog.d/01-xen-shutdown-script.conf':

> template(
> name="xenShutdownScriptFormat"
> type="string"
> string="<%syslogprioriy-text%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %msg%\n"
> )
>
> if $syslogtag contains "xen-shutdown-script" then /var/log/xen-pool-shutdown.log;xenShutdownScriptFormat

Comment: Is this the entire *code* from `01-xen-shutdown-script.conf`?

Comment: Yes, it is the entire file. I noticed that there was a line break missing in my post between the template and conditional directives, so I fixed it.